# Android mobile: scroll performed properly, but scroll not stopping on corresponding lookup value defined against selector arguments

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-java

In Appium (android) I am using mobile command mobile:scroll to scroll, based on this [reference](https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver#mobile-scroll).
Scrolling is working perfectly, but not not stopping on corresponding lookup value defined against selector arguments.

**Code**

```
@AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.NumberPicker\")")
private MobileElement mobileElementNumberPickerYear;
    
HashMap<String, Object> scrollYearObject = new HashMap<>();
scrollYearObject.put("elementId", mobileElementNumberPickerYear.getId());
scrollYearObject.put("strategy", "-android uiautomator");
scrollYearObject.put("selector", "new UiSelector().text(\"2027\")"); // not stopping at this
getBaseMobileDriver().executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollYearObject);
```

**Log**

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/722e2055-847f-42a1-8d1c-23e879881719/element
[HTTP] {"using":"-android uiautomator","value":"new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.NumberPicker\").index(1)"}
[debug] [W3C (722e2055)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["-android uiautomator","new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.NumberPicker\").index(1)","722e2055-847f-42a1-8d1c-23e879881719"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, css selector, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/ea9b5a0b-4529-4d6d-9d5b-f59114246b31/element] with body: {"strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.NumberPicker\").index(1)","context":"","multiple":false}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"ea9b5a0b-4529-4d6d-9d5b-f59114246b31","value":{"ELEMENT":"00000000-0000-04b7-ffff-ffff00000086","element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"00000000-0000-04b7-ffff-ffff00000086"}}
[debug] [W3C (722e2055)] Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"00000000-0000-04b7-ffff-ffff00000086","ELEMENT":"00000000-0000-04b7-ffff-ffff00000086"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/722e2055-847f-42a1-8d1c-23e879881719/element 200 170 ms - 137
[HTTP]
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/722e2055-847f-42a1-8d1c-23e879881719/execute/sync
[HTTP] {"script":"mobile: scroll","args":[{"elementId":"00000000-0000-04b7-ffff-ffff00000086","strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"new UiSelector().text(\"2027\")"}]}
[debug] [W3C (722e2055)] Calling AppiumDriver.execute() with args: ["mobile: scroll",[{"elementId":"00000000-0000-04b7-ffff-ffff00000086","strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"new UiSelector().text(\"2027\")"}],"722e2055-847f-42a1-8d1c-23e879881719"]
[AndroidDriver] Executing native command 'mobile: scroll'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /touch/scroll] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/ea9b5a0b-4529-4d6d-9d5b-f59114246b31/touch/scroll] with body: {"origin":{"ELEMENT":"00000000-0000-04b7-ffff-ffff00000086","element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"00000000-0000-04b7-ffff-ffff00000086"},"params":{"strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"new UiSelector().text(\"2027\")"}}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"ea9b5a0b-4529-4d6d-9d5b-f59114246b31","value":null}
[debug] [W3C (722e2055)] Responding to client with driver.execute() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/722e2055-847f-42a1-8d1c-23e879881719/execute/sync 200 35403 ms - 14
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't stop to the lookup value, very likely it doesn't match exactly the String passed.

Try to use `textContains(...)` rather than `text(...)`.

Comment: I double checked and this was not the case